# Why is PHP $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] different on local and production servers?

Tags: php

I have a 404 page that sends a Slack message through a CURL request to Zapier, before redirecting to a different page.

```
<?php
    /* Send a silent alert to Slack to record the missing page, then redirect to /apply */
    $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];


    $url = "https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/<webhook_id>";

    $curl = curl_init();

    $data = array("page"=> array("href"=> "https://$host$page"));

    $jsonEncodedData = json_encode($data);

    $opts = array(
        CURLOPT_URL             => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POST            => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => $jsonEncodedData,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER  => array('Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($jsonEncodedData))  
    );

    curl_setopt_array($curl, $opts);

    curl_exec($curl);

    header("Location: https://$host/apply");

?>
```

I'm seeing different behavior from this code on my local set up (MAMP PRO), and the production set up (nearlyfreespeech.net).

On localhost, it works perfectly. So if I load the page: `localhost:8888/not-a-page`, I get a slack alert with the full url: `https://localhost:8888/not-a-page`.

However, on the server, the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable appears to be blank, and I'd get a slack alert with just the root domain of the production site: `https://example.com` instead of the desired `https://example.com/not-a-page`. However, if I add a file extension to the url like `https://example.com/not-a-page.php`, then the full URL comes through correctly.

I'm stumped. Any ideas on what to check?

#### EDIT

Thanks to Justinas for the advice to check for redirects. I double checked my `.htaccess` file, and saw that I had set up the 404 handler like this: `ErrorDocument 404 /alert404`, instead of `ErrorDocument 404 /alert404.php`.

So there was a redirect from `alert404->alert404.php` happening that for some reason was setting the `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` variable to an empty string before the alert script ran. Making that change fixed the problem.

That said, I'm still not sure why this was behaving differently on my local server and production servers.

Comment: Check server configuration and if there is any redirect

Comment: `$_SERVER` is different on every server. That's the point. if you need to distinct environments, then make use of [getenv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv) which is best practice especially in the docker world.